# Row command event not firing for image button in gridview?

Tags: .net, gridview, rowcommand

I have a gridview with an image button in each row.I have set the command name and command argument .

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="1" CellSpacing="1" CssClass="one-column-emphasis" DataKeyNames="Id" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">

<asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" AlternateText="Register" CssClass="buttonreg" EnableTheming="False" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' CommandName="register" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

I get the following error,

> Invalid postback or callback argument.
>       Event validation is enabled using  in
>       configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.
>       For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback
>       or callback events originate from the server control that originally
>       rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
>       ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to 
>       register the postback or callback data for validation.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

When you are using gridview, bind this in

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        Binddatagrid();
    }
}
```

register your [ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms223397.aspx) postback method

Comment: I have a dropdownlist contains month also.The gridview binded based on the month selected. When i am using your code gridview shows no data.

Comment: or set EnableEventValidation for the page to false

Answer (score 1):

Set AutoPostBack property of DropDownList to False.Make sure that in Page_Load event,

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
      //Call Grid() function.
    }

}
```

Call the Grid() function in the SelectIndexChanged event of DropDownList.
Thankx all for help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

Html code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="mygrid" CssClass="reportgrid" EmptyDataRowStyle-CssClass="userwel"
                                        DataKeyNames="JudgementId, titles, Is_Active" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="800px" runat="server" OnRowCommand="mygrid_RowCommand">
<EmptyDataTemplate>  
 No Data Found.
</EmptyDataTemplate>
 <Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
 <ItemTemplate>                                           
<asp:Label ID="label_Address" Text='<%# Bind("titles")%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblstatus" Text='<%# Bind("Is_Active")%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit" ItemStyle-Width="43px">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgedit" runat="server" alt="Edit" Height="40px" Width="40px"
src="../Images/Edit.png" CommandName="edit1" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DisplayIndex %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" ItemStyle-Width="43px">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgdelete" runat="server" alt="Edit" Height="40px" Width="40px"
src="../Images/delete.png" CommandName="delete1" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DisplayIndex %>' OnClientClick="return ConfirmationBox();" />
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View" ItemStyle-Width="43px">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgview" runat="server" alt="Edit" Height="40px" Width="40px"
src="../Images/view.png" CommandName="view1" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DisplayIndex %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

.cs code

```
 protected void mygrid_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int row = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);        
                int JudgementId = Convert.ToInt32(gvL_Judgement.DataKeys[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)]["JudgementId"]);
                if (e.CommandName == "edit1")
                {
                    //code to edit
                }
                if (e.CommandName == "view1")
                {
                    //code to view
                }
                if (e.CommandName == "delete1")
                {
                    //code to delete
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The FillGrid() method must be called like.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        FillGrid();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is an old thread but thought of replying cause I had a hard time finding the solution for this.

The solution is you have to use    `if (!IsPostBack)`

but in my case i had nothing written in my Page_Load event of the .aspx page but I had below code in my master page.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.DataBind();
}
```

once I put that Page.Databind(); inside if (!IsPostBack) problem solved.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Page.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Hope somebody find this usefull.